# Return all type of android device supported Audio, Video and File formats

Tags: android, android-file

As we know different android device could support different types of file formats and I want to make program that could return all types of supported image, audio format and file format(pdf, docx, etc..) of a device. Any keywords what should i use to google? and is there is any links for a page that i could refer to, and if there is any example of codes will be much appreciated.

Here is an example in case you are not understand

this is the list of device supported formats that returned programmatically.

### **List of supported image/vide/file/format of Samsung Gt-5231 :-**

supported audio format:

- -mp3

supported file:

- -txt
- -docx

supported image and video format:

- -3gp
- -mp4
- -wmv
- -avi

---

### List of supported image/video/file formats of Samsung S7 edge

supported audio format:

- vma
- m4a
- mp3

supported images format

- tiff
- jpg
- png
- jpeg

supported video format

- amv
- mp4
- flv

supported file format

- pdf
- docx
- doc
- xls

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "support different types of file formats" means and what "return all types of supported image, media files and file format (pdf, docx, etc..) of a device" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare here i already edited it, please see this.

Comment: Dude can you help me ? no one is responding to this :( . @CommonsWare

Comment: You did not explain, **in detail**, what "support different types of file formats" means and what "return all types of supported image, media files and file format (pdf, docx, etc..) of a device" means. You edited your question to include some bulleted lists of file extensions, with no explanation of what they have to do with anything. You need to explain, to us, what you, as a programmer, are trying to do.